# GTK+ with Broadway

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, wayland

I am trying to use GDK Broadway backend on Raspbian jessie.

```
sudo broadwayd -a 192.168.0.3 -p 80 :5 &
```

Runs and server and I can access from browser http://192.168.0.3/ but most of the applications can not recognise the X display even when setting the right env vars. (using fishshell)

```
set -g -x LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR 0;set -g -x GDK_BACKEND broadway; set -g -x DISPLAY :5;set -g -x BROADWAY_DISPLAY 80;set -g -x UBUNTU_MENUPROXY 

epiphany-browser
```

ends with `** (epiphany-browser:15222): WARNING **: Could not open X display`. same as iceweasel. I am not sure if I need to install extra GTK packages..

Comment: I think I will need to compile the browser from source with extra flags for this to work or just wait for Maynard!

Comment: You might want to consider not using GDK Broadway for the time being, as the traffic is at present not encrypted (yet - it's still evolving and I don't doubt it will work someday).